# Send Firebase Swift Push using NSURLSession HTTP Post

Tags: swift, firebase, httprequest, firebase-cloud-messaging

I set up my app so that users when they login subscribe to a topic with their user UID. Whenever a user sends a message to another user I will be calling the function below that I am hoping to trigger the push.

```
func sendPushNotification(toUser: String, message: String) {
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let topic = "\topic\\(toUser)"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let paramString  = "to=\(topic)"

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Based on Firebase docs I am supposed to do this HTTP request:

```
Send to a single topic:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

I am struggling to see what I pass in the paramString for the message to be sent based off of their example. Also, where do I define the Authorization:key=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a message with Firebase Cloud Messaging requires that you provide your **server key** in the `Authorization` header. As the name suggests, this key should only be used in code that runs on an app server (or other infrastructure that you control). Putting the server key into the app that you ship to your users, means malicious users can use it to send messages on your behalf.

From the [Firebase documentation on sending messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging#build_send_requests) (emphasis mine):

> From the **server side**, sending messages to a Firebase Cloud Messaging topic is very similar to sending messages to an individual device or to a user group. The **app server** sets the to key with a value like `/topics/yourTopic`.